# XPath returning the wrong Boolean result

Tags: xml, xpath, saxon

I am trying to run an XPath via Saxon, I have the following Document:

```
<ServiceContext>
    <userName>admin</userName>
</ServiceContext>
```

Which I then load into a XdmItem called doc and then I run the following query

```
XPathExecutable expr = compiler.compile("/ServiceContext/userName/text()='admin'")
final XPathSelector selector = expr.load();
selector.setContextItem(doc);
final boolean value = selector.effectiveBooleanValue();
```

It should return true but it returns false for some reason, does anyone know whats wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: This should work. To see what the value actually is (that you expect to be `'admin'`), you could try `compiler.compile("/ServiceContext/userName/text()")` and then print the value `final String value = selector.effectiveStringValue()`

Comment: No, I can't see what's wrong here. I suspect it's something in the part of the code that you haven't shown us. Have you tried executing the expression from the XQuery command line?

Comment: Yes it has to do with a piece of the code that wasn't shown the compiler had the wrong URN set

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Saxon but using the off-the-shelf `javax.xml` classes, it works as expected.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();

Document d = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream("<ServiceContext>\n<userName>admin</userName>\n</ServiceContext>".getBytes()));
String value = xpath.evaluate("/ServiceContext/userName/text()='admin'", d);
```

`value` contains `true`.
Perhaps upgrade your Saxon or switch to `javax.xml`.